# Is Feynman correct to speak of "delivering entropy"?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature, entropy

In his lecture on entropy found [here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_44.html#Ch44-S6), Feynman says

> Any heat $\mathrm{d}Q$ that has been absorbed from the substance at temperature $T$ has now been converted by a reversible machine, and a certain amount of entropy $\mathrm{d}S$ has been delivered at the unit temperature as follows:
> $$\mathrm{d}S=\frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T}$$

I understand that the quantity of heat delivered to the reservoir at temperature $T_s=1^\circ$ by a reversible machine absorbing heat $\Delta{Q_1}$ at temperature $T_1$ will be

$$\frac{\Delta{Q_1}}{T_1}=\frac{\Delta{Q_s}}{T_s}=\frac{\Delta{Q_s}}{1^\circ}=S,$$

which is numerically equal to the entropy corresponding to the heat absorbed at $T_1.$

But this is the only context where I have encountered the notion of "delivering entropy".  If a cylinder of gas at $T_1$ is adiabatically expanded until its temperature is $1^\circ$, then isothermally compressed using a reservoir at $T_s=1^\circ$ we can't examine that reservoir to find the entropy we supposedly "delivered", can we?

Is it typical or even correct to speak of "delivering entropy"?

Also, his statement says that the entropy $\mathrm{d}S$ delivered at $1^\circ$ is not part of "Any heat $\mathrm{d}Q$ that has been absorbed from the substance at temperature $T$..." since all of $\mathrm{d}Q$ "...has now been converted by a reversible machine...".  But $\mathrm{d}S=\mathrm{d}Q_s,$ where $\mathrm{d}Q_s$ is a quantity of heat. Shouldn't $\mathrm{d}Q_s$ be included in $\mathrm{d}Q$?

Comment: It's just a word choice, maybe not the best word choice. As  entropy is not conserved, any  increase does not have to come *from* somewhere else.  It's not  delivering groceries.

Comment: "Is it typical or even correct to speak of "delivering entropy"?". We normally speak of entropy "transfer" which occurs every time heat is transferred. It is transferred reversibly if the temperature difference is infinitesimal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entropy, as the [conjugate thermodynamic variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_variables_(thermodynamics)) to temperature, is the "stuff" that's transferred or shifted when a temperature difference drives energy flow. (You can think of this as analogous to a pressure difference driving a shift in volume, or a surface tension difference driving a shift in area, or a stress difference driving a shift in strain, or, more generally, a gradient in an [intensive variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties) driving a shift in the corresponding conjugate extensive variable. An energy transfer always accompanies these shifts.)

(Entropy—unusually for an extensive thermodynamic parameter—is also generated whenever a real (irreversible) process occurs, but that isn't relevant in this discussion of an idealized reversible process.)

So yes, it seems perfectly reasonable for Feynman to speak of delivering entropy from one system to another. This is the essence of heat transfer.

Comment: Technically, entropy, $S(\bar{E})$ divided by the Boltzmann constant is the Legendre Transform of the Helmholtz free energy, $F(\beta)$ multiplied by $\beta$. So it's the average energy of the system ($\bar{E}$) and thermodynamic temperature ($\beta$) that are conjugate variables. But in any case I agree with your analysis, one can "exchange" entropy for energy in the sense that free energy corresponds to work done.

Comment: *"So it's the average energy of the system (E¯) and thermodynamic temperature (β) that are conjugate variables."* In this case, you're working with a [fundamental relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_thermodynamic_relation) of $(1/k)dS = (1/kT)dU + (P/kT)dV-(\mu/kT)dN$ (where $\beta=1/kT$), which isn't more or less correct than $dU = T\,dS - P\,dV+\mu\,dN$.

Comment: Yes, but more difficult to compute the actual Legendre transform in the standard form. The standard way the equation is written confuses what the actual conjugate variables are.

Comment: @Chemomechanics do other authors write of "delivering entropy"?  I believe I understand why Feynman uses this terminology.  The presentation is quite insightful, but it certainly could use improvement.  But it's pretty good for a guy standing up talking for 11 minutes 59 years ago.  It starts about 43 minutes in https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_44.html#Ch1-audio

Comment: "Deliver" in this context is uncommon, as delivery is usually associated with something beneficial, and entropy is rarely sought, it being created constantly. In the context of cryptography, though, authors sometimes write about delivering reliable randomness or informational entropy to encode information. Feynman often chose evocative terms to prompt careful thought leading to insight, which I hope is the case here.